# Shopify App - define url to redirect when app is selected form app list of a shop

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I'm new to shopify app development and trying to build a shopify app with node and followed this post [here](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/building-node-app). Everything worked as explained, but I have things to get clarified, may be very basic things.

My question is where to specify the link that's directed when shop owner select my app from the installed apps list of the shop?

As I understood from the post above `App URL` given in the App info section of the app is used for installation process and from there it's redirected to one of the `Whitelisted redirection URL(s)` as defined in the app for `HMAC` validation and exchanging a permanent access token to access the shops' admin API later.

Now Once my test-app is installed to a shop and when the app is selected from the installed apps list, the request again goes to the `App URL` and get redirected to `callback URL` generating a new access token. If this is how it is supposed to be, why it's called a permanent access token and need to be stored? If this not how it should be how to specify a url to direct when the app is selected from the installed app list?

**In Short**

where to define the url to direct when a shop admin select the app from is installed apps section of the shop like shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After install the HMAC validation and temp code is just to get the permanent token, which you should then store securely in a database.

You don't have to show any of that process to the user using your app; you can have it happen in the background and then redirect to whatever route you like after you have the permanent token.

Comment: thank you for the answer, what I don't get is where to define the url that directs when the app is clicked from the installed app of the shop

Comment: I mean after installtion, there can be many times a user visits the app by clicking the icon under apps installed in the shop

Comment: I believe that the App URL is what you want, it's just a matter of checking whether you have a permanent token for that store already before going through the access token step or indeed the install step.

Comment: can you please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861502/shopify-product-images